# Create Table by From Range using MS Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new at VBA for MSAccess.  What I am trying to do is to create a new table from each group of name e.g.

```
Name  Email  Company

Abby  Abby@Time.com  Time    
BeeT  Beet@Share.com Share    
BeeT  Beet@Share.com Share    
BeeT  Beet@Share.com Share    
Carol Carol@Total.com Total    
Carol Carol@Total.com Total
```

What I want to do is to create a new table from each Billing Name so that in this case there will be 3 new tables e.g.

```
Name  Email  Company

Abby  Abby@Time.com  Time
```

```
Name  Email  Company

BeeT  Beet@Share.com Share    
BeeT  Beet@Share.com Share    
BeeT  Beet@Share.com Share
```

```
Name  Email  Company

Carol Carol@Total.com Total    
Carol Carol@Total.com Total
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to do this.  You can actually loop through the table, and if the table already exists then you can append the data to the table.  If it doesn't, then you can create a new table.  This involves checking the database objects for existing names and is more work.

The easiest way would be to just create a table for each billing name and then filter your original table to add appropriate rows.

```
Dim db as Database
dim rec as Recordset
Dim rec2 as Recordset
Dim tbl As TableDef
Dim fld As Field
Dim fld2 as Field

Set db = CurrentDB
set rec = db.OpenRecordSet ("Select DISTINCT Company from YourTableName")

Do While rec.EOF = False
   Set rec2 = db.OpenRecordSet ("Select DISTINCT * from YourTableName WHERE Company = '" & 
   rec("Company") & "")
   Do While rec2.EOF = False
      Set tbl = dbs.CreateTableDef(Rec2("Company"))
      Set fld = tbl.CreateField(Rec2("Name"), dbText)
      Set fld2 = tbl.CreateField(Rec2("Email"), dbText)

      tbl.Fields.Append fld
      tbl.Fields.Append fld2
      db.TableDefs.Append tbl
      db.TableDefs.Refresh
      rec2.MoveNext
   Loop
   rec.MoveNext
Set rec2 = Nothing
Loop

Set db = Nothing
Set rec = Nothing
Set rec2 = Nothing
```

Comment: I tried over the weekend and it fail.  I keep on hitting syntax error

Comment: I need to know exactly what the error is, and exactly what line it's happening on. I can help you, but I need more detailed feedback.

Comment: Hi Johnny, I manage to get that resolve but what came out is not that it create a table called share and two fields call Name BeeT and Beet@Share.com.  What I actuall wanted is to create some random table say Table1, Table2, Table3 and each table has fields Name, Email and Company with data of company eg Table1, Fields Name, Email, Company with data Abby Abby@Time.com Time, and Table2, Fields Name, Email, Company with data BeeT Beet@Share.com Share etc.